# Filtering rows in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a dataset with columns containing numbers. However, some of the rows in that column have missing data. Instead of numbers, a dash (-) is placed in the cell.

What I want to happen is to separate those rows with a dash and output them to a separate excel file. Those without the dash, should output to a csv file.

I tried the "filter rows" but it gives me an error:

```
Unexpected conversion error while converting value [constant String] to a Number

constant String : couldn't convert String to number 

constant String : couldn't convert String to number : non-numeric character found at position 1 for value [-]
```

My condition is if

```
Column1 CONTAINS - (String)
```

Comment: Is your incoming field defined as a number maybe? It's probably best to define it as a string and then convert the "good" rows to number again after filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You cant try to convert to number in the select step,and handler the error, if can not convert to number that mean that is (-)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can convert missing value indicators (like a dash or any other string) to null in Text-File-Input - see field option "Null if".  That way you still can use the metadata detection feature and will not trip over a dash arriving in a Number field.

With CSV-File-Input you should stick to the String datatype until a Null-If step has cleansed the values, so you can change the datatype to Number in a Select-Values step.

If you must preserve the dash character, don't use metadata detection (as it suggests datatype Number) or use more rows to sample (so a field with a dash is encountered) or just revert the datatype to String again before saving and running the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

My solution lies on the first 'Replace in String'. I replaced the dash into something numeric and can easily be distinguished from the rest of the numbers (I used 9999) and carried on with the rest of my process.

In filter rows, I had no problems anymore with the data type because both my variables and condition contained numbers, therefore, it no longer had to convert anything.

After filter rows, I added the 'Null-if' to remove the random 9999 that I used
just to have something to replace the dash.

After that, the separation was made just as I hope it would.

Thanks to @marabu for the Null-if idea.

[image: See image]